# Linq union list (property) of a list of objects

Tags: c#, linq, list, linq-to-entities

I have two classes, Person and Group

```
class Person {
    public virtual ICollection<Group> GroupsWhereIAmMember { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Group> GroupsWhereIAmSender { get; set; }
}

class Group {
    public virtual ICollection<Person> Members { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Person> Senders { get; set; }
}
```

Given a person instance p, **how can I get all the persons that belong to groups where p is sender?**

The linq to objects way would be this:

```
List<Person> results = new List<Person>();

foreach (Group group in p.GroupsWhereIAmSender)
{
     results.AddRange(group.Members);
}
```

But I want to do it the "linq-to-entities" way so I dont run out of memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `SelectMany`:

```
results = p.GroupsWhereIAmSender.SelectMany(g => g.Members);
```

Answer (score 2):

The "linq-to-objects" way would be to use `SelectMany` as already suggested and the "linq-to-entities" way would be to also use `SelectMany` but to have a `DataContext` as the source (an `IQueryable` to be precise).

In both cases the expression is: `p.GroupsWhereIAmSender.SelectMany(g => g.Members)`
(you may want to add `Distinct` to the result in order to avoid duplicate values).

The difference between "linq-to-objects" and "linq-to-entities" is that "linq-to-entities" uses `IQueryable` and an expression tree that can be converted into T-SQL at runtime. This way filtering and sorting can be done on the underlying database instead of loading everything into memory.

Your code however does not show any hint that there is a `DataContext`. So I have to assume that all your data is already in memory. Therefore you won't run out of memory because `SelectMany` will not load/produce new data.